# Origen del estribillo "colorín colorado" para finalizar cuentos

Tags: expresiones

Ahora que día sí día también uso el estribillo *[colorín colorado, este cuento se ha acabado](https://dle.rae.es/?id=9qtzRMN#8yefj3A)* cada vez que termino de leerles un cuento a los niños, me preguntaba desde cuándo se usa. Así que me puse a buscar información, y lo primero que encuentro es que al parecer un *colorín* es un tipo de pájaro:

> COLORIN. s. m. Lo mismo que Xilguero. Dixose assí por lo pintado y vario de sus plumas.

Esta definición es de 1729, aunque en diccionarios anteriores del siglo XVII parece que *colorín* se define como un tipo de rojo. Por tanto, tenemos dos opciones: que *colorín colorado* se refiere a un pájaro rojo o sencillamente sea una forma redundante de referirse al color rojo. Posiblemente sea una expresión usada sencillamente por su sonido y rima, más que por su significado. Sin embargo, un texto del mismo siglo XVII (extraído del CORDE) ofrece un giro de tuerca a la historia:

> *—¿Eres Satanás? —prosiguió el estudiante.
>
>   —Ése es demonio de sastres y carniceros —volvió la voz a repetille.
>
>   —¿Eres Bercebú? —volvió a preguntalle don Cleofás.
>
>   Y la voz a respondelle:
>
>   —Ése es demonio de tahúres, amancebados y carreteros.
>
>   —¿Eres Barrabás, Belial, Astarot? —finalmente le dijo el estudiante.
>
>   —Ésos son demonios de mayores ocupaciones —le respondió la voz—: demonio más por menudo soy, aunque me meto en todo; yo soy las pulgas del infierno, la chisme, el enredo, la usura, la mohatra; yo truje al mundo la zarabanda, el déligo, la chacona, el bullicuzcuz, las cosquillas de la capona, el guiriguirigay, el zambapalo, la mariona, el avilipinti, el pollo, la carretería, el hermano Bartolo, el carcañal, el guineo, el colorín colorado; yo inventé las pandorgas, las jácaras, las papalatas, los comos, las mortecinas, los títeres, los volatines, los saltambancos, los maesecorales y, al fin, yo me llamo el Diablo Cojuelo.*
>
> Luis Vélez de Guevara, "El diablo cojuelo", 1641 (España).
>
> <sup>[Original en Google Books](https://books.google.es/books?id=jApvWyjuaZgC&pg=PA5-IA2&dq=%22color%C3%ADn%20colorado%22&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_vJK7n-bhAhUGxYUKHbHcDzI4FBDoAQhUMAg#v=onepage&q=%22color%C3%ADn%20colorado%22&f=false)</sup>

Hay multitud de palabras que desconocía en este texto, pero lo curioso es que aparece la expresión *colorín colorado* en una lista de bailes. Los enumero:

- *[Zarabanda](https://dle.rae.es/?id=cNhnlFj)*: Danza popular española de los siglos XVI y XVII, que fue frecuentemente censurada por los moralistas. El *Autoridades* dice literalmente que el baile se hace con movimientos "poco modestos".
- *Déligo*: No encuentro definiciones, pero sí este texto de 1605: *Vi de lejos que había baile y, pardiez, no me pude contener, que, sin apearme de la carreta, puse en razón mis castañuelas y en el aire repiqué mis castañetas de repica punto, a lo deligo, y di dos vueltas a buen son.*
- *[Chacona](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8SDRmac)*: Baile español de los siglos XVI y XVII, muy extendido por Europa.
- *Bullicuzcuz*: Valgan estos versos de Quevedo: *Zarabullí, ay, bullí, / bullí, de zarabullí; / bullicuzcuz de la Veracruz. / Yo me bullo y me meneo, / me bailo, me zangoteo, / me refocilo y recreo / por medio maravedí.*
- *Capona*: Según el *Autoridades*, "son ò baile à modo de la Mariona; pero mas rápido y bullicioso, con el qual y à cuyo tañido se cantan varias coplillas".
- *Guiriguirigay*: Sin definición pero encuentro un texto de 1656 en el que dos músicos cantan esta letra: *¡Ay! ¡Ay! / ¡Ay! ¡Reay! / ¡Tatara, ay! / ¡Guiri, guiri, guirigay!*
- *[Zambapalo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=cJAq5aW)*: Danza grotesca traída de las Indias Occidentales, que se usó en España durante los siglos XVI y XVII.
- *[Mariona](https://dle.rae.es/?id=OQklMRI)*: Especie de danza antigua.
- *Avilipinti*: Solo encuentro una ficha en el fichero general de la RAE, que parece confirmar que el autor del texto citado da una lista de los bailes populares de la época.
- *Pollo*: No encuentro nada acerca de un baile dado lo común de la palabra, pero debió de ser algo parecido al baile de los pajaritos.
- *[Carretería](https://dle.rae.es/?id=7gzlg7B)*: Baile del siglo XVII a imitación de los que usaban los carreteros y trajinantes.
- *El hermano Bartolo*: Una ficha del fichero general de la RAE confirma que era un baile popular de la época, con letra propia, que se bailaba por parejas dispuestas en filas de ambos sexos y que, alternativamente y cuando lo indica la copla, se remudan él o ella.
- *Carcañal*: Igual que con *avilipinti*, solo encuentro algunas fichas en el fichero general que confirman que era un baile popular típico de la época.
- *[Guineo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=JqZuTvT)*: Cierto baile de movimientos violentos y gestos cómicos, que era propio de la gente de raza negra. El *Autoridades* dice que se baila con gestos "poco decentes".

Para rematar esta retahíla cita "el colorín colorado". Lo que ignoro es si lo hace usando la expresión usada en los cuentos para decir "hasta aquí la lista de bailes", o si por entonces la expresión no se usaba en los cuentos, y realmente el colorín colorado era un tipo de baile. Si es así se abre la posibilidad de que el estribillo usado en los cuentos haga referencia a un baile. Sin embargo, este uso de *colorín colorado* parece anecdótico, puesto que el primer uso escrito de la expresión aplicada a los cuentos lo encuentro en un *Quijote* comentado de 1781 [según Ngram](https://books.google.es/books?id=OrM9AQAAIAAJ&q=%22color%C3%ADn%20colorado%22&dq=%22color%C3%ADn%20colorado%22&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_vJK7n-bhAhUGxYUKHbHcDzI4FBDoAQhQMAc):

> *[...] que de casta le viene al galgo ser rabilargo, que en boca cerrada no entran moscas, que al buen callar llaman Sancho, y como el cuento era colorín, colorado se fué por el alto del tejado [...].*

Así pues, indaguemos para ver si realmente hay alguna relación entre la expresión y el baile o si fue pura casualidad. ¿Desde cuándo se usa el estribillo "colorín colorado" para finalizar los cuentos? ¿Cuál es su origen?

Answer (score 3):

## Colorín colorado

Tenemos esta definición del siglo XVIII:

> COLORíN, **ó** COLORíN COLORáDO, ſe dice como jocoſamente , de una tela , ó coſa mui pintada , ó teñida de muchos , y lucidos colores.
>
> - [*Diccionario castellano con las voces de ciencias y artes y sus ...*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rpVgQDEcD7kC&pg=PA463&dq=%22color%C3%ADn+colorado%22) (1786)

No sé si venía primero el significado del baile (a que también se refiere en una nota en una edición de la misma década de [*Don Quixote*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pdANAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA387&dq=%22colorin+colorado%22)), o del color, o a cuál refiere el estribillo, pero según el CORDE y [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=color%C3%ADn+colorado&year_start=1000&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3) no se usaba mucho el estribillo hasta el siglo XIX.

El uso más antiguo que he encontrado es esto:

> ... que de casta le viene al galgo ser rabilargo, que en boca cerrada no entran moscas, que al buen callar llaman Sancho, **y como el cuento era colorín, colorado** se fué por el alto del tejado del Palacio Parnaso submarino ...
>
> - [*Rudolph Schevill Cervantes collection, Volume 232*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=OrM9AQAAIAAJ&dq=%22color%C3%ADn+colorado%22) (1781)

## Frases para acabar un cuento

El uso de un ['stock phrase'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_upon_a_time) para empezar o terminar un cuento es común de muchos idiomas y culturas e.j. *"Once upon a time... and they lived happily ever after."* y *"Érase una vez... colorín, colorado, este cuento se ha acabado."*.

Adicionalmente, muchas de estas frases emplean rimas y ideas incongruentes (cf. los ejemplos Nepalí y Turco en el enlace arriba).

En catalán en particular, hay una frase muy similar de la de castellano:

> Vet aquí un gat, vet aquí un gos, aquest conte ja s'ha fos.
> I vet aquí un gos, vet aquí un gat, aquest conte s'ha acabat.

Así, creo que (como tú dices) "colorín colorado se refiere a... una expresión usada sencillamente por su sonido y rima, más que por su significado." como muchos otros ejemplos.

Podemos ver esto definitivamente en las frases alternativas :

> *Y **arroz** crudo, para el diablo barbudo,* o *Y **arroz** de munición, para el diablo rabón,* o *Y **arroz** de Calcuta, para el diablo hijo de puta.*
>
> Fórmulas con que se suele terminar el relato de los cuentos o consejos.
>
> - [*Diccionario de refranes, adagios, proverbios modismos, locuciones y frases proverbiales de la lengua espanola*](https://archive.org/details/diccionarioderef01sbaruoft/page/68) (1920)

Comment: Y por poner un ejemplo adicional de "expresión usada sencillamente por su sonido y rima, más que por su significado" para acabar un cuento, tenemos el "**y fueron felices y comieron perdices**" o (del CORDE): **Y colorín colorete por la chimenea ha salido un cohete. Y colorín colorao, cuento acabao.**

Comment: @Charlie: En el CORDE he encontrado algunos casos en que aparece invertido el uso: **Colorado colorín, aquí tiene el cuento fin.** o cambiado: **Y colorín colorete por la chimenea ha salido un cohete. Y colorín colorao, cuento acabao.**

Comment: [Structure and Analogy in the Playful Lexicon of Spanish](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GZYDDgAAQBAJ&q="the%20existence%20of%20this%20type%20in%20Spanish")

Answer (score 1):

Añado otra hipótesis… Neotrombicula autumnalis, un ácaro muy común del campo español que afecta a animales y personas (habitual cuando se va al monte a coger setas por ejemplo). Es una especie de garrapata, más pequeña, de color rojo bermellón y que en todos los pueblos se llama colorín. El colorín colorado. Produce prurito intenso y en ocasiones síntomas mayores, peligrosos, si la picadura es múltiple o el organismo atacado tiene la inmunidad comprometida. Hay muchas historias y cuentos de transmisión oral en los pueblos sobre este ácaro.
A valorar este colorín colorado.

[image]

Comment: Puedes editar tus publicaciones sin problema. Pulsa donde pone [edit] y corrige lo que creas conveniente.

Comment: Muy bueno esto. :)